# How to add a segue from the last page of a UIPageViewController with Swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

Im trying to implement a tutorial with 3 screens and at the last page, when the user swipes, the app should go to the main UIViewController. When the pageViewController data source is set to self, no swipe gestures are recognized. Is there a work around for this?

```
class TourViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var pageTitles: NSArray!
var pageImages: NSArray!
var pageDesc: NSArray!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.pageTitles = NSArray(objects: "page 1", "page 2", "page 3")
    self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "image 1", "image 2", "image 3")
    self.pageDesc = NSArray(objects: "note 1", "note 2", "note 3")
    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
    var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as! [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height-60)

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self

}
```

Following is the function I would like to be called by the swipe gestures. This works when the pageViewController data source is set to nil

```
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.direction == .Left) {
        print("Swipe Left")
    }

    if (sender.direction == .Right) {
        print("Swipe Right")
    }
}
```

Is there something that I can do in my following function?

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int
    print(index)
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil
    }

    index++
    if (index == self.pageTitles.count) {
        return nil
    }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}
```

Couldn't find any swift example on this. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I found the way to do it. Try some condition inside func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {} .. it worked.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but scrollViewWillBeginDragging is not called at any swiping. What am I missing?

Comment: Let me test your code....

Comment: I am sure I got that function working this morning...let me try again from your code...

Comment: I just found the answer for your problem.first download sample project from this link https://github.com/Weijay/PageViewController-Example  and run let me know what you thing...

Comment: I will help you to modify the sample project and make it work on your favour...

Comment: Let me know..if you want the answer as we agreed earlier...